# Create one Object in client side using multiple tables

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure mobile apps with .NET backend and Xamarin as client app.

I have multiple tables as follows:

1. `Badges` - where badge description is stored
2. `Achievmentgroups` - one group can have multiple badges .e.g badge x level 1 ,badge x level 2 , badge y level 1 ,badge y level 2... etc
3. `CustomerAchievments` - where the progress of each badge is stored for each user

`Badges` and `achievmentsgroups` are linked together with foreign key lets name it `achievmentGroupId`.

`CustomerAchievments` and `Badges` are linked together with foreign key lets name it `BadgeId`

In my client side, I would like to create one object from these three tables.
currently what I am doing is getting each table separately and i want to utilize object oriented programming more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of what I understand from your question The easiest way of doing this would be bunching them together so what your final class would look like is as shown below:

```
public class Customer 
{
   public Badges  Badges { get; set; }

   public Achievmentgroups  Achievmentgroups  { get; set; }

   public CustomerAchievments  CustomerAchievments { get; set; }
}
```

In this way, your .Net backend can send just one class and that can be used to get all your data individually!

Comment: wouldn't Badges be a list of badges instead of one badge , something like this :  public ObservableCollection<Badge> Badges { get; set; }

Comment: That is just an example, my man you can obviously change it however you feel and based on your conditions and code

Comment: the bunching is done in the client side or should i create a custom API table that do the bunching on the server and return one JSON ?

Comment: Obviously, you should do it on the Web-API side send that from the service as JSON and then deserialize at the client and use as you please, doing it this way will just require one API call

Comment: ill just leave this link here for anyone who is following this question .
https://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2014/04/29/consuming-azure-mobile-service-custom-api-with-net-backend.aspx

Answer (score 0):

a solution with an example here :

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/05/27/retrieving-data-from-1n-relationship-using-net-backend-azure-mobile-services/